# how to replace [10-15] to 10 11 12..15 in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a file/string containing the following:

```
[1-9]
[11-12]
[10-15]
```

I then want to expand that to become this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
11 12
10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I know how to do it in a very long way (first capture the two numbers and then expand them using a for loop).

I would like to know if there is a faster/smarter way of achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions.

Solution 1:

```
sed 's/^/echo /; s/[[]/{/; s/]/}/; s/-/../' | bash
```

Example:

```
$ cat 1.txt | sed 's/^/echo /; s/[[]/{/; s/]/}/; s/-/../' | bash
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
11 12
10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Solution 2:

```
tr '[]-' ' ' | sed "s/^/seq -s' '/" | bash
```

Example:

```
$ cat 1.txt | tr '[]-' ' ' | sed "s/^/seq -s' '/" | bash
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
11 12
10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:(Pure bash solution)

```
while IFS=- read l1 l2
do
   eval echo ${l1/[/{}".."${l2/]/}}
done < file
```

Comment: Simple and neat. You could also use `while IFS=-[] read x l1 l2 y` and simplify the construction of the sequence expression accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident that your input all matches that pattern:

```
while read a; do
  seq -s' ' $(echo "$a" | tr '[]-' ' ')
done
```

Add error checking as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```sh
cat lines | sed -E -e 's/\[|]//g' -e 's/-/ /g' | xargs -n 2 seq -s ' ' -t '\n'
```

As in:

```sh
$ cat <<EOF | sed -E -e 's/\[|]//g' -e 's/-/ /g' | xargs -n 2 seq -s ' ' -t '\n'
> [1-9]
> [11-12]
> [10-15]
> EOF
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
11 12
10 11 12 13 14 15
```